# How do I use a custom XSL style sheet with a Content Query Web Part without SharePoint Designer?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, xslt, content-query-web-part

I'm trying to present data from a list in a more beautiful fashion using a Content Query Web Part and an XSL style sheet.

I found some instructions on [this page](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2012/01/26/how-to-customize-sharepoint-list-content-display-using-content-query-web-part-aspx/), which seem pretty simple, but they require SharePoint Designer in order to edit the `ItemStyle.xsl` file and insert my own style. At my work, I'm not allowed to use SharePoint Designer.

Is there a way to edit this file or otherwise specify a custom XSL to use without using SharePoint Designer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Map Network Drive feature - from there on you can use any IDE you want. The process differs depending whether you are connection to Sharepoint Online(Office 365) or On-prem. See this links below:

- Sharepoint Online http://nikpatel.net/2014/12/23/mapping-network-drive-for-office-365-and-sharepoint-online/
- Sharepoint On-prem https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn151472.aspx

Comment: We have on-prem SharePoint. I tried mapping my sub-site to my drive, but I merely see my own site contents; it doesn't provide access to the style sheets I'm wanting to edit. I tried mapping the parent site to my machine, but I see nothing in the folder.

Comment: Add <URL>/_catalogs/masterpage at the end when you're adding new network drive connection. Also, try Show Hidden Files/Folders from Folder Options in Explorer. Hope it helps. Let us know.

Comment: Also. check using browser (navigate to site) and verify that there is indeed Styles Library - Publishing Feature must be activated to see this.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check the presence of a Styles Library. Unfortunately on the root site, I have limited permissions. Your suggestion of adding `/_catalogs/masterpage` to the end of the URL has certainly provided access to a lot of additional files. I've mapped the root site using this URL, but sadly no `ItemStyle.xsl` file exists. In fact, there is only one XSL file: `ServerRenderTemplate.xsl`.

Comment: @Duncan You can manually download, edit and upload the xsl file to style library. But if you have limited access that not seeing the directory, then you possibly can't override it either.

Comment: Solution: drop a CSWP or SEWP on page, then use REST and SPService to achieve the same thing @Duncan

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies to SP2013, it is for SP2010

If you are only showing a single list you can also use a "normal" list view webpart (XLV). In the settings there is an option to define an XSL-link in the misc. tab.

There are lots of guides about customizing XSL of an XLV.